# how to fix this code all the android screens

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

[image] below code I wrote for android but this design is not fitting all the android screens

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_status"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/wight"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tseriesname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/series_name"
            android:textColor="@color/textgraycolor"
            android:textSize="10.0sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/list_border_back_red"
            android:text="Live"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15.0sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_match"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_status"
        android:layout_weight="0.14"
        android:background="@color/wight"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/flag_team1"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:src="@drawable/flag1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_name1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="KKR"
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_score_team1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.32"
            android:background="@color/wight"
            android:baselineAligned="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score_team1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="160/3"
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/over_tem1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="(ov : 20)"
                android:textColor="@color/textgraycolor"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vs"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/vs"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/vs"
            android:textColor="@color/wight"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_score_team2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.32"
            android:background="@color/wight"
            android:baselineAligned="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score_team2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="140/2 "
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/over_tem2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="(ov: 18.3 )"
                android:textColor="@color/textgraycolor"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/flag_team2"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:src="@drawable/flag2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_name2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="MI"
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_over_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_match"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.16"
        android:background="@color/wight"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/re_rr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Required RR : 2.56"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cu_rr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Current RR: 5.36"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.40"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="OVER 19"
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView05"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundtxt4"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="@color/wight"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView04"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundtxtw"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="W"
                android:textColor="@color/wight"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundtxtb"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="NB"
                android:textColor="@color/wight"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundtxt6"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="6"
                android:textColor="@color/wight"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundtxt0"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="."
                android:textColor="@color/wight"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/o1"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundtxt4"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="@color/wight"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Mubai Indians  needed 91 runs in 9 balls to win. "
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_over_details"
        android:background="@color/txt_full_score"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:text="Full ScoreBoard"
        android:textColor="@color/wight"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/batting_table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/txt_full_score"
        android:weightSum="1" 
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/Batting_heading_Row"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.40" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:text="BATTING"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="R"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="B"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="4s"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="6s"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="SR"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/Batting_one_row"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.30" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:text="Aroan Finch"
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="30"
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="36"
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="54.55"
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/Batting_two_row"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.30" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:text="Rohid Sharma"
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="80"
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="40"
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="6"
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/wight"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="101.40"
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/batting_table"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#F44238"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:text="Full Commentary"
        android:textColor="@color/wight"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="68.0dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="56.0dip"
            android:layout_height="56.0dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/image_thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="48.0dip"
                android:layout_height="48.0dip"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@color/ball6"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:text="6"
                android:textColor="@color/wight" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="56.0dip"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="69dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6.0dip"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="David Warner and Joe Burns started off positively and added 49 runs before the former was caught behind when he gloved one off Wagner. Khawaja and Burns then made sure Australia don&apos;t lose any further wickets and negotiated the last few overs."
                android:textColor="@color/txtscore"
                android:textSize="13.0sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Definitely its not gonna fit like the way you want to handle it. The design you have thought of looks good for mobile devices but its not the ideal one for tablet. Your issue has more to do with the way you visualize your app then its implementation. It will be easy to provide solution once you decide how you want your design yo look like in Tabs. If you want Commentary section  to always be at bottom you can align it to parent bottom and adjust other things respect to that. It will be easy in your design as you are using Relative layout.

Comment: Just put `ScrollView` as parent of all layers, there is no way them to fit exactly on all screens

Answer (score 4):

You are using custom `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes in the xml, hence this xml code will be differently viewed in different devices with different screen sizes.

I would suggest you to study the following developer docs:

[Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

[Supporting Different Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

Answer (score 2):

Either you can use `ScrollView`, or use different folders for different layout sizes -

```
layout-ldpi (Low DPI phones)
layout-mdpi (Medium DPI phones)
layout-hdpi (High DPI phones)
layout-xhdpi (Very High DPI phones)
layout-xxhdpi (Very Very High DPI phones)
```

If you are using Android Studio, it will automatically tell which DPI is suitable for which screen size.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are using static height and width for all control, first of all remove it and use `wrap_content`.
2. When it comes to image, keep multiple copies of image in respected folder like `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-xdpi`, `drawable-xxdpi`.
3. If your `TextView` is having large value in future, try to keep it in single line.
4. Use `LinearLayout` for main partition of your view. Use of `weightsum` would help you in more complex situation.
5. Try to use `dimen.xml` for text size.
6. If you think design is more complex, you can use different layout folders also.

Answer (score 1):

Since your using static height and weight in dp,

you should define something like this for multiple screen size :

> In values folder:
>
> dimen.xml file:

```
    <!-- Margins -->
    <dimen name="margin1">1dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin2">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin3">3dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin5">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin7">7dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin10">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin11">11dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin13">13dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin15">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin18">18dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin20">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin25">25dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin27">27dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin30">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin35">35dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin40">40dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin45">45dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin50">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin55">55dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin60">60dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin65">65dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin70">70dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin75">75dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin80">80dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin85">85dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin90">90dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin95">95dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin100">100dp</dimen>

    <!-- Text Size -->
    <dimen name="text8">8sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text10">10sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text11">11sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text12">12sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text13">13sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text14">14sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text15">15sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text16">16sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text17">17sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text18">18sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text19">19sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text20">20sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text21">21sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text22">22sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text23">23sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text24">24sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text25">25sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text26">26sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text28">28sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text30">30sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text32">32sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text34">34sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text35">35sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text36">36sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text38">38sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text40">40sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text50">50sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text60">60sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text65">65sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text70">70sp</dimen>
    <!-- height -->
    <dimen name="height110">110dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height120">120dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height130">130dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height140">140dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height150">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height160">160dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height165">165dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height170">170dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height175">175dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height180">180dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height185">185dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height190">190dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height195">195dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height200">200dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height220">220dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height250">250dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height300">300dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height330">330dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height350">350dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height400">400dp</dimen>

    <!-- Size -->
    <dimen name="size30">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="size35">35dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="size50">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="size75">75dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="size80">80dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="size100">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="size120">120dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="size130">130dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="size150">150dp</dimen>

    <!-- Padding -->
    <dimen name="padding1">1dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding2">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding3">3dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding4">4dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding5">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding6">6dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding7">7dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding8">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding9">9dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding10">10dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

> In values-sw600dp folder
>
> dimens file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Margins -->
    <dimen name="margin1">1dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin2">3dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin3">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin5">7dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin7">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin10">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin11">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin13">19dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin15">22dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin18">27dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin20">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin25">32dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin27">40dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin30">45dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin35">47dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin40">60dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin45">62dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin50">75dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin55">85dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin60">90dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin65">97dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin70">105dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin75">110dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin80">120dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin85">127dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin90">135dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin95">142dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin100">150dp</dimen>

    <!-- Text Size -->
    <dimen name="text8">12sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text9">13sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text10">15sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text11">16sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text12">18sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text13">19sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text14">21sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text15">22sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text16">24sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text17">25sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text18">27sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text19">28sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text20">30sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text21">31sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text22">33sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text23">34sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text24">36sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text25">37sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text26">39sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text28">42sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text30">45sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text32">48sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text34">51sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text35">52sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text36">54sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text38">57sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text40">60sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text50">75sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text60">90sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text65">97sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text70">105sp</dimen>

    <!-- height -->
    <dimen name="height110">165dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height120">180dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height130">195dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height140">210dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height150">225dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height160">240dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height165">245dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height170">250dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height175">260dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height180">270dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height185">275dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height190">285dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height195">293dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height200">300dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height220">330dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height250">375dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height300">495dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height330">440dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height350">525dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height400">600dp</dimen>

    <!-- Padding -->
    <dimen name="padding1">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding2">3dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding3">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding4">6dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding5">7dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding6">9dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding7">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding8">12dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding9">13dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding10">15dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

> In values-sw-720dp
>
> dimens.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Margins -->
    <dimen name="margin1">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin2">4dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin3">4dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin5">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin7">14dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin10">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin11">22dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin13">26dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin15">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin18">36dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin20">40dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin25">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin27">54dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin30">60dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin35">70dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin40">80dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin45">90dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin50">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin55">110dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin60">120dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin65">130dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin70">140dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin75">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin80">160dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin85">170dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin90">180dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin95">190dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin100">200dp</dimen>

    <!-- Text Size -->
    <dimen name="text8">16sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text10">20sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text11">22sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text12">24sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text13">26sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text14">28sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text15">30sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text16">32sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text17">34sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text18">36sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text19">38sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text20">40sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text21">42sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text22">44sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text23">46sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text24">48sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text25">50sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text26">52sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text28">56sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text30">60sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text32">62sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text34">68sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text35">70sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text36">72sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text38">76sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text40">80sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text50">100sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text60">120sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text65">130sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text70">140sp</dimen>

    <!-- height -->
    <dimen name="height110">220dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height120">240dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height130">260dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height140">280dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height150">300dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height160">320dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height165">330dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height170">340dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height175">350dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height180">360dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height185">370dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height190">380dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height195">390dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height200">400dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height220">440dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height250">500dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height300">600dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height330">660dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height350">700dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height400">800dp</dimen>

    <!-- Padding -->
    <dimen name="padding1">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding2">4dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding3">6dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding4">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding5">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding6">12dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding7">14dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding8">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding9">18dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding10">20dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

after doing this your able to change ur layout xml file like this:

I have just altered one Linear layout file

you should apply for all other layouts in this xml file

```
See this below sample:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_status"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/wight"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tseriesname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"       
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin20"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/series_name"   
            android:textColor="@color/textgraycolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text10"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
..........
..............
................
...................
```

like this way your app should able support multiple screens.

you can use differ layouts for supporting devices.

and should have images in drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xdpi, drawable-xxdpi for perfect view of images.

I think this ll be helpful for ur answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a lot of things you can do

1. use **android:layout_weight** and **android:weightSum**
   a good example can be found by google search like [layout weight](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-android-s-layout-weight-attribute.html)
2. You could also use the **Android Percent Support Library** [example](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/) and some [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/package-summary.html)
3. You can have different  resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for small, medium, high, and extra high density screens.

```html
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
 res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
 res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
 res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
 res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

 res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
 res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
 res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

4. You could support for Smallest Width layout directories, and have individual layouts there for 5", 7", 10" and so on.

   ```
     res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 480dp available width)
     res/layout-sw480dp/main_activity.xml   # For phones (480dp wide and bigger)
     res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
     res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
   ```
5. You can also have different value folders to have different dimens.xml for each screen resolution group
   [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use google's design library. [Percentage Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) it will fulfill your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the Parent Layout as Linear Layout and then setting `android:weightsum` property to parent. Finally, align the child view using weight as `android:weight`property. In this way, you can have uniform UI across all the screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `layout_weight` and change the 
`android:layout_width="(fixedvalue)"` 
and `android:layout_height="fixed_value"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent`" and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. You can do some research and you will find this easy to understand.

Answer (score -1):

You can create you layout through code rather than layout.xml.